# Matrix norm of orthogonal matrices induced by $p$-norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is an orthogonal matrix. Then the matrix norm induced by the Euclidean norm satisfies $\| A \|_2 = 1$. Are there similar results for matrix norms $\| A \|_p$ induced by $p$-norms with $p \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, they are norms generally speaking

Comment: Why would you expect anything to hold for $p\neq 2$ ?

Comment: You need some notion of orthogonality.

Comment: @copper.hat: By assumption $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: I don't have any expectations.

Comment: @user355419: I mean when you use the $p$-norm, you give up the inner product.